# Docker compose does not create users ,password and database for mysql8

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My docker compose does not create mysql user,database even though i have passed them as environmental variable.here is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
web:
  image: zadiki1/posshop-webapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - db
    - phpmyadmin
  environment:
    HOST: db
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'posshop'
    USER_NAME: 'zadik'
    PASSWORD: 'zadik'
db:
  image: mysql:8
  command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    MYSQL_USER: 'zadik'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'zadik'
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'posshop'
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  expose:
        - '3306'
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin-dot
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
    - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

when i go to the mysql server both the database and the user are not created
I have searched online but cant find a solution

Comment: Check the logs as it boots up to see if those are being applied or not.

Comment: @tadman nothing is being logged about user creation or db creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables are used to configure access to existing resources within the database. If you need to have a database `posshop` and a user `zadik` in the `db` (`mysql:8`) instance, you will need to create these against the database server **before** you can access them, e.g. from `web`.

It is slightly inconvenient to do this with Docker Compose but, in my experience, a successful solution is to use e.g. a docker volume to persist the database server configuration, create the database and user while the server's configured to use this for persistence. Then, reference it subsequently in a configuration (as yours) that depends upon it.

It's possible but more challenging to have another container added to your Docker Compose that creates these assets and blocks e.g. `web` from starting until this is done.

Comment: This is not quite true as the mysql image (along with many images) automatically provision the user/database/root password based on environment variables on first-time setup (new volume). If you look at the entrypoint, it will show the creation of those mentioned objects - https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

Your docker-compose.yml file is correct (at least for the db service). It will create everything you configured - root password, user, and database.

See below:

Using the exact same yaml as you for the db service:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:testmysql myuser$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_USER: 'zadik'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'zadik'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'posshop'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
    expose:
      - '3306'
```

Start containers:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:testmysql myuser$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "testmysql_default" with the default driver
Creating testmysql_db_1 ... done
```

Exec into mysql container:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:testmysql myuser$ docker-compose exec db bash
```

Connect with root and list databases (which shows posshop):

```
root@aeba05c5cc08:/# mysql -u root -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| posshop            |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

Connect with user (zadik/zadik):

```
root@aeba05c5cc08:/# mysql -u zadik -pzadik
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| posshop            |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> use posshop;
Database changed
mysql>
```

Additional note: As stated in the other answer you should also create a volume to persist data (although that wasn't the question).